# Gridlayout textfield search issue codenameone

Tags: codenameone

I had used gridLayout with 2 columns. When i search(code is below), the textArea component stays in its own possition. Those which are hidden also take their places. If i use boxLayout instead of gridLayout, it works fine but there is only one column.

problem after searching

[image]

```
Container wrapContainerMinute = new Container(new GridLayout(connection.responseMenu.size() / 2+1, 2));
f.add(wrapContainerMinute);
for (Map<String, Object> entrySet : connection.responseMenu) {
    String tableName = (String) entrySet.get("name");

    Container singleMinuteMenuContainer = new Container(new BoxLayout(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    TextArea minuteTextArea = new TextArea(tableName);
    minuteTextArea.setEditable(false);
    minuteTextArea.getAllStyles().setAlignment(Label.CENTER);
    minuteTextArea.setScrollVisible(false);
    minuteTextArea.setRows(20);
    minuteTextArea.setGrowByContent(true);
    minuteTextArea.setGrowLimit(2);
    singleMinuteMenuContainer.add(minuteTextArea);
}

minuteSearchTextField.addDataChangeListener(new DataChangedListener() {

@Override
public void dataChanged(int type, int index) {
    String searchTableName = minuteSearchTextField.getText().toLowerCase();
    boolean show = false;
    for (Component c : wrapContainerMinute) {
        Container searchedContainer = (Container)c;
        TextArea searchedTextArea = (TextArea) searchedContainer.getComponentAt(0);
        c.setVisible(true);
        if (searchedTextArea.getText().toLowerCase().indexOf(searchTableName)>-1) {
            show = searchedTextArea.getText().toLowerCase().indexOf(searchTableName)>-1;
            c.setHidden(!show);
            c.setVisible(show);
        }else{
            show = searchedTextArea.getText().toLowerCase().indexOf(searchTableName) > -1;
            c.setHidden(!show);
            c.setVisible(show);
        }
    }
    wrapContainerMinute.animateLayout(1500);
}
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The setHidden is giving the component a (0,0) preferred size which hides the Component, GridLayout ignores the Components preferred size because it splits the Container to equal sized cells.
What you need to do is to remove and add the Components instead of using the setHidden

Comment: Or use `myGridLayout.setHideZeroSized(true)` which we added to support this exact same issue in the settings UI. Should have written a blog post about it but it got buried under the tasks...

Comment: Thank you, setHideZeroSized works perfectly. If I remove component as in the answer, there is a problem. When the searched text in the textfield is deleted or edited, I have to re-add the components but the components are already removed.